Java Web Push Notification
I have a java application: the backend developed with Spring, and the front end with React.
Now I have turned my web application into a PWA, and I am trying to send Web Push Notifications from the backend to my app. The purpose is to notify the user that some particular event has happened in their application, even if the app is not currently open.
How would I go about implementing that? The only library that I have found seems to be the Webpush-java library, which looks like it hasn't been maintained in a long time.
Are there any alternatives out there?
EDIT:
I have managed to use firebase as a service to send the push notifications to my PWA. The problem is, I only receive the notification, but no sound is played, and not even the blue phone light flickers. In my use case it is pointless having a notification without a sound and vibration to alert the user.
In summary - I converted my web application into a PWA by adding a manifest and a service worker. The app is now installable on the device.
I receive push messages from the backend and I attempt to show them on the client side using:


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        tag: payload.data?.tag,
        renotify: true,
        requireInteraction: true,
        vibrate: [500, 200, 500, 200, 100, 200, 100],
        icon: './images/icons/icon-128x128.png',
        badge: './images/icons/icon-128x128.png',
    };
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});



Notifications are being displayed on the phone, but no sound is played, no vibration, and not even the flickering light to indicate there's a new notification.

This Java library for web push is simple to use and still maintained: https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-java It also allows to target specific users, as required by your use case. However it uses a proprietary / paid service

for implementing push notifications, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging. Check out the details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Does that not require a Firebase project? My project is not Firebase

You can use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) without converting your entire project to Firebase. You just need to create a Firebase project to obtain the necessary credentials for FCM. Once you have the credentials, you can integrate FCM into your existing project to send and receive notifications. It won't require you to migrate everything to Firebase, just to use its messaging service.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
